# How to extract hyperlink address from excel cell using spreadsheet gem in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, import-from-excel

I have tried retrieving data from Excel sheet cells. I could retrieve the general text from each cell. but I couldn't get hyperlink  address from the cell. I used ***spreadsheet*** gem with Ruby.
I have used below code to read excel sheet.

```
book = Spreadsheet.open('C:\Downloads\CallStreetData.xls')
sheet1 = book.worksheet(0)
rowArray = Array.new
sheet1.each do |row|

  puts row.join(',')
  rowArray.push(row.join(',').href)
end
puts rowArray
```

I need a solution with Ruby and ***Spreadsheet*** gem

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that will probably work to print out both the text and the links:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open('C:\Downloads\CallStreetData.xls')
sheet = book.worksheet(0)

sheet.rows.each do |row|
  row_text = row.join(",")
  row_links = row.to_a.map do |cell|
    cell.respond_to?(:href) ? cell.href : ""
  end.join(",")

  puts(row_text)
  puts(row_links)
end
```